# Hadoop HDFS dependency

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In hadoop mapreduce programming model; when we are processing files is it mandatory to keep the files in HDFS file system or can I keep the files in other file system's and still have the benefit of mapreduce programming model ?

Comment: What file system do you want to use? Something like a mysql database or something?

Comment: I have log files sitting on server; I want to use log files of type ext4

Comment: So what you really want is to access files that are not being piped to an hdfs directory? So is a better question how can I use a MapReduce engine of files not stored in HDFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mappers read input data from an implementation of `InputFormat`. Most implementations descend from `FileInputFormat`, which reads data from local machine or HDFS. (by default, data is read from HDFS and the results of the mapreduce job are stored in HDFS as well.) You can write a custom `InputFormat`, when you want your data to be read from an alternative data source, not being HDFS.

`TableInputFormat` would read data records directly from HBase and `DBInputFormat` would access data from relational databases. You could also imagine a system where data is streamed to each machine over the network on a particular port; the `InputFormat` reads data from the port and parses it into individual records for mapping.

However, in your case, you have data in a ext4-filesystem on a single or multiple servers. In order to conveniently access this data within Hadoop you'd have to copy it into HDFS first. This way you will benefit from data locality, when the file chunks are processed in parallel.

I strongly suggest reading the [tutorial from Yahoo!](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#inputformat) on this topic for detailed information. For collecting log files for mapreduce processing also take a look at [Flume](http://flume.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the files elsewhere but you'd lose the data locality advantage.
For example. if you're using AWS, you can store your files on S3 and access them directly from Map-reduce code, Pig, Hive, etc.

Comment: @djc391: S3 can be a HDFS-like storage, where the data for mapreduce will be stored in HFDS or be directly read from S3 = without HDFS. See http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3.

Comment: It's a "replacement" for hdfs, because instead of your own server hdfs cluster you use amazon's hdfs cluster. It's without using ONES OWN hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

In order to user Apache Haddop you must have your files in HDFS, the hadoop file system. Though there are different abstract types of HDFS, like AWS S3, these are all at their basic level HDFS storage.

The data needs to be in HDFS because HDFS distributed the data along your cluster. During the mapping phase each Mapper goes through the data stored in it's node and then sends it to the proper node running the reducer code for the given chunk.

You can't have Hadoop MapReduce, withput using HDFS.